# Parsing a nested tag, moving it outside of the parent, and changing its type using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have HTML coming from an API that I want to clean up and format it.

I'm trying to get any `<strong>` tags that are the first element inside a `<p>` tag, and change it to be the parent of the `<p>` tag, and convert the `<p>` tag to `<h4>`.

For example:

```
<p><strong>This is what I want to pull out to an h4 tag.</strong>Here's the rest of the paragraph.</p>
```

becomes:

```
<h4>This is what I want to pull out to an h4 tag.</h4><p>Here's the rest of the paragraph.</p>
```

EDIT: Apologies for the nature of the question being too 'please write this for me'. I posted the solution I came up with below. I just had to take the time to really learn how Nokogiri works, but it is quite powerful and it seems like you can do almost anything with it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far, and an example of the input you're working with and the desired output.

Comment: Edited to add an example.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please edit your question to describe what you've tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a tag but keep the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861338/remove-a-tag-but-keep-the-text)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. You haven't showed any evidence of effort, which makes it look like you didn't really try. We want to see what you tried so we can correct it, rather than act like a code-writing service and help write your program for you. Yes, what you want to do is easily done, but again, without seeing your effort we're less inclined to help you. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)

doc.css("p").map do |paragraph|
  first = paragraph.children.first
  if first.element? and first.name == "strong"
    first.name = 'h4'
    paragraph.add_previous_sibling(first)
  end
end
```